Claim that is supported by the spec of the provisional but not the non-provisional
A non-provisional application claims a provisional application.
questions:

Does the spec of the non-provisional application have to include everything in provisional?
If not, can a claim in the non-provisional be not supported by the spec of the non-provisional, but instead supported by the spec of the provisional?


It’s a little complicated but, if done properly, you can incorporate the entire provisional by reference. Then it is availing to hemp support claims in the non provisional.
Separately you can use it as a source to amend in inadvertently omitted items. Let’s imagine you forgot to include a drawing.
